# how to allow running javascript on my WebPage?

Tags: javascript, web-services, iis-7.5

i have html page that "talk" with my `WebService` by `POST`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a#SayHello").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
        //ServiceCallID: 1,

        url: 'http://localhost/Z_WS/HelloWorld.asmx/Hello', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: '{"name": "' + $("input#name").val() + '"}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',

            success:
              function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        alert("IN");
            alert(data.d);
         },
            error:
              function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
              }
          });
        });
      });
```

i know that i need to insert my IP like this:

```
 url: 'http://192.168.22.MyIP/Z_WS/HelloWorld.asmx/Hello',
```

but when i do it - I did not get any response from the server

i work with `IIS 7.5`

thanks

Answer (score 0):

*When you make that kind of request will give you an error Crost Browser, try this way with jsonp*
````

```
    $("a#SayHello").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/Z_WS/HelloWorld.asmx/Hello', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"name": $("input#name").val() }, //Is an Object, no String
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'jsonp', //Is this
            success:function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                alert("IN");
                alert(data.d);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
```

I guess you know when you'll try from another machine you have to change the localhost IP

Enjoy!

Comment: yes i know, but if i change to my ip - its dont work

Comment: thanks for the help, i try with jsonp and now i can put my ip insted of localhost - but when i write the link to my page from the browser with the ip (http://192.192.44.MyIP/Z_HTML/) i see the page, but i dont get any answer from my WebService